# How do i get this firebase data to use it outside the loop?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, nuxt.js

I have this script that runs through all the child items in my realtime database from firebase:

```
methods: {
        submit: function() {
            const gebruikersref = firebase.database().ref('Gebruikers/')
            var self = this
            gebruikersref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
                const lid = self.lidnummer;
                const voornaam = self.voornaam;
                const achternaam = self.achternaam;
                const email = self.email;

                snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                    const data = childSnapshot.val()
                });
                if(lid == data.Lidnummer) {
                        console.log('err')
                    } else {
                        gebruikersref.push({
                            Voornaam: voornaam,
                            Achternaam: achternaam,
                            Email: email,
                            Lidnummer: lid
                        });
                    }
            });
        }
    }
```

but how do i get `const data = childSnapshot.val()` outside the foreach loop so i can use it here:

```
if(lid == data.Lidnummer) {
  console.log('err')
} else {
    gebruikersref.push({
      Voornaam: voornaam,
      Achternaam: achternaam,
      Email: email,
      Lidnummer: lid
    });
}
```

Otherwise the else method runs x times the number of children and will push my data (that only may be pushed once) x times the children

Comment: Declare it at a higher scope, which can be seen by the code that needs to use it?

Comment: Yes i know that so that it can be seen but how do i declare it at the higher scope from the lower scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, since the asynchronous [`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) method returns a [`ThenableReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ThenableReference), you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
    submit: function() {
        const gebruikersref = firebase.database().ref('Gebruikers/')
        var self = this
        gebruikersref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
            const lid = self.lidnummer;
            const voornaam = self.voornaam;
            const achternaam = self.achternaam;
            const email = self.email;

            const promises = [];
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                const data = childSnapshot.val()
                if (lid == data.Lidnummer) {
                    console.log('err')
                } else {
                    promises.push(gebruikersref.push({
                                Voornaam: voornaam,
                                Achternaam: achternaam,
                                Email: email,
                                Lidnummer: lid
                            })
                    );
                }
            });
            
            Promise.all(promises);
            
        });
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer @Renaud Tarnec but this is the answer thank you very much! :)